# Flutter if email correct show pop-up

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to this condition:

- if email is correct, show pop-up before going to the next page
- if email is not correct, then there is a warning in the textfield

Here is my code:

```
Scaffold (
 body: Padding(
         Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: TextFormField(
              cursorColor: Color(0xFF2481CF),
              autofocus: true,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty || !EmailValidator.validate(value.trim())) {
                  return 'Email is not valid!';
                }
                return null;
              },
              controller: _controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF2481CF)),
                  ),
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF2481CF)),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Enter your email :',
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF2481CF)
                  )
                ),
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 19.0,
                height: 1.3,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
 
 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () => showDialog<String>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
          content: Container(
            height: 110,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text('We will be verifying the email address'),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                Text('Is this OK or would you like to edit the email address?'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
              child: const Text('Edit',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFF2481CF)
              ),),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: _submit,
              child: const Text('Yes',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFF2481CF)
              ),),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: const Icon(Icons.send),
    ),
);

void _submit(){
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      /*ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('Sedang memproses.')),
      );*/
      //kirim email

      sendEmail(_controller.text.trim());

      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  PinVerification(_controller.text.trim())),
      );
    }
  }
```

This is the output when I type in the wrong email format, it shows the popup then the warning:

[image]

What I want is if the email format is not correct then it shows only the warning.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have displayed a dialog on `floatingActionButton`. So you need to check the validation of the email first and then display the dialog. Check out the code below.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
            showDialog<String>(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                  AlertDialog(
                    content: Container(
                      height: 110,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Text('We will be verifying the email address'),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 30,
                          ),
                          Text(
                              'Is this OK or would you like to edit the email address?'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
                        child: const Text('Edit',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xFF2481CF)
                          ),),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: _submit,
                        child: const Text('Yes',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xFF2481CF)
                          ),),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
            );
          }
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.send),
      ),
```